# Is there a way to stub/intercept a javascript statement 'throw' in vanilla javascript?

Tags: javascript, throw

We can stub any function or class like this,

```
class ErrorStub{
        constructor(message){
                // do whatever with 'message'
        }
}
Error = ErrorStub
new Error('This will go to ErrorStub now')
```

Similar to this, is there any way we can intercept a 'throw' statement. So that whatever exception is thrown across whole website, can be handled in one place?

Comment: Maybe [error event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onerror) is what you need? It can handle runtime errors only, though.

Comment: `throw` is a little different as it's a keyword.

Comment: "*whatever exception is thrown across whole website, can be handled in one place?*" - it sounds like you don't want to intercept every `throw`, but rather handle those errors that have not already been caught in a normal `catch` clause

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wouldn't this satisfy your needs? You would need to listen to the `error` event, handle it the way you want and `return false`

```js
function interceptError(exception) {
  // Here you can write code which intercepts before
  // the error gets triggered and printed in the console
  alert(`Exception occured: ${exception.message}`)
}

window.addEventListener("error", function (e) {
  interceptError(e);
  return false;
})

throw new Error('Test exception');
```